# Get specific values from CURL JSON response php array

Tags: php, arrays, json, curl

Trying to echo a couple of values from the CURL JSON response so i can put them in to a foreach loop but i can only get single indexed values to work.

```
$request = curl_init($api); // initiate curl object
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); // set to 0 to eliminate header info from response
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); // Returns response data instead of TRUE(1)
//curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); // uncomment if you get no gateway response and are using HTTPS
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
  "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
));

$response = (string)curl_exec($request); // execute curl fetch and store results in $response

curl_close($request); // close curl object

$result = json_decode($response, true); // true turns it into an array
echo 'First Name: ' . $result['first_name'] . '<br />'; // why doesnt this work
echo 'Last Name: ' . $result[0]['last_name'] . '<br />'; // yet i can return the first value
```

Example Array output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 34761
            [first_name] => A
            [last_name] => Bailes
            [clinic] => 
            [phone] => 7409923279
            [fax] => 7409926740
            [address1] => 507 Mulberry Heights Rd
            [address2] => 
            [city] => Pomeroy
            [subdivision] => OH
            [country_code] => 
            [postal_code] => 45769-9573
            [timezone] => Array
                (
                    [timezone_type] => 3
                    [timezone] => America/New_York
                )

            [state] => OH
        )
)
```

I have json decode set to true for array output

```
$result = json_decode($response, true); // true turns it into an array
```

but when i try to echo the 'first_name' values it just returns empty.

```
echo 'First Name: ' . $result['first_name'] . '<br />'; // why doesnt this work
```

Yet i can return an indexed value

```
echo 'First Name: ' . $result[0]['first_name'] . '<br />';
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: `$result[0]['first_name']` is correct. See your array structure. Otherwise, you can set `$result = json_decode( $response, true )[0]` (on php >= 5.5)

Comment: what's the problem. you are getting the value by `$result[0]['first_name']` right? `$result` is an array with 1 element in which is your associative massive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your result array is nested 2 deep.  `$result` is an array of arrays.  So:

```
$result[0]['first_name']
```

or

```
foreach ($result as $r) {
    echo $r['first_name'];
}
```

Comment: Sorry i'm not understanding. $result[0]['first_name'] works but will only get one result, the first in the index. I need to output all the results in a foreach loop but i only want specific e.g. the first_name values. When i use it in a foreach loop foreach ($result as $r) {
    echo $r['first_name'];
}i get empty results (nothing is shown).

Comment: That's strange. The `foreach` should definitely work. I suggest running it through a debugger and checking the values.

Comment: Turns out it was an undefined index error because i had $result['first_name'] earlier. That was my problem all along. foreach loop working now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Response depend on server answer your request, the following work perfect to extract access token for example, you can try the following steps to test what you have and extract what you need too
After

```
$response = curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close($ch);
```

I start to show what I get by 
Test:

```
print_r ($response);
```

Then go to extract (where server response ) header and body to use what available in each of them

```
list($header, $body) = explode("\r\n\r\n", $response, 2);
```

Test:

```
echo $header;
echo $body;
```

then I’m extract item in $body to use in my code using `stdClass`

```
$bodyObject = json_decode($body);
```

Test:

```
print_r($bodyObject);
```

Test:

```
echo $bodyObject->access_token;
```